# Need help in understanding the proof for Theorem 11.17 in Baby Rudin

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory

[image]

I don't understand why the first two equality signs hold in the proof.

Answer (score 1):

$g(x) > a \iff \sup_n f_n(x) > a$, i.e. there is some $n$ for which $f_n(x) > a$. So, $$\{x \mid g_n(x) > a\} = \bigcup_{n=1}^\infty \{x \mid f_n(x) > a\}.$$
The second equality sign follows by definition of the $\limsup$.

Comment: $\{x \mid g(x) > a\} $ means all the $x$ such that $g(x) > a$, but what about $\{x \mid sup f_n(x) > a\} $? All the $x$ such that  $sup f_n(x) > a$? The choice of $x$ shouldn't affect the $sup$ of $f(x)$ right?